# string.Contains function is not working as expected in my golang code. Though first string contains the second string, condition fails

Tags: string, if-statement, go

I am checking some shell command output in golang. I need to check whether the output contains my input string.

```
//myinput is a valid string
 stdoutput2,stderr2,err2 := Shellout("some valid shell command | grep "+myinput)
        if(err2!=nil){
        glg.Error("Not able to retrive information from system")
        glg.Error(err2)
        return false
        } else if strings.Contains(strings.TrimSpace(stdoutput2),myinput){
        glg.Info("able to retrive information from system")
        return true
      } else {
                glg.Error("Not able to retrive information from system")
                glg.Error("stdoutput2 after trimming is-->"+strings.TrimSpace(stdoutput2))
                glg.Error("myinput is :"+myinput)
                glg.Error("std error is :"+stderr2)
                return false
        }
```

Here though stdoutput2 contains the value of myinput, my else if condition is failing.

**The final output is**

Not able to retrive information from system.
stdoutput2 after trimming is-->  Name                  = customcsi-b35f3ea733
myinput is :customcsi-b35f3ea733

---

Please note the space between Name and = symbol. That is part of output.

Please help in resolving this. My golang version is 1.13.5

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Rest assured that strings.Contains works as documented. If it returns false where you expect it to return true your assumptions are wrong. When debugging strings use the %q fmt verb so whitespace and unprintable characters become obvious. There's not much more we can do to help you without a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: After trimming my inputs (before applying strings.Contains function) , it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a newline at the end of `myinput`?

You could try

```
stdoutput2, stderr2, err2 := Shellout("some valid shell command | grep " + myinput)    
myinput = strings.TrimSpace(myinput)
```

Comment: Worked for me. After applying TrimSpace for myinput, it worked perfectly. Thanks.